# Can i add a paypal support/donate button on my opensource project on github in India(Specifically). And How should i do it?

Tags: paypal, donation, open-source

I am an open source developer from India .I am opening up an open source project on github . I want to set up a paypal (support/donate/or whatever name is appropriate to put in India) on my github page. Now So I have read on paypal community link - https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Selling/Accepting-Donations-in-India/m-p/1447506#M3808 that only export related payments are allowed in India and somewhere i saw donations for charity are not allowed but this is not a charity or NGO. And i am not sure if that is entirely true because I have seen blogs that have paypal donate button in india on their websites.

I will be giving taxes to the government as i understand its not non-profit an its income.

Now I wanted to know what is the procedure to create a support button or should i use a Paypal.Me link . And which paypal account do i need to choose for this purpose.Like do i need to create a business account or a freelancer account. (i am not a registered business. Two people in my team(me and one person from a different country) and what should be my purpose code in paypal for recieving payments(India specifically)

I have read the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716143/how-to-integrate-a-donate-button-into-a-website-in-india I didnt find relevant information in this and its old and Indian rules have changed .

Answer (score -1):

This part of Stack Exchange is not for coding projects even if they relate to money. I would suggest posting this on Stack Overflow instead. You probably could just have like a

`<%= link_to "Donate Now", paypal_new_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>`

In Ruby at least. I don't know what language you are using. Open source is not a language

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking about how to _code_ such a button (which would be off-topic), but more what methods (if any) are there for dealing with India/PayPal's "obstacles" to having a "Donate" button. Whether that in itself it on-topic or not, I'm not sure.